# Which one is correct please? Firm's representative < at / to / in > the union?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am the representative of our firm **at** the union.
I am the representative of our firm **to** the union.
I am the representative of our firm **in** the union.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What does this role entail? Are you a member of the union? Please see the [tag help for prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info) and [edit] your question to provide all relevant information. The meaning of a sentence can be dramatically altered by choosing the wrong preposition, so we need to know what the meaning should be in order to help find the correct preposition.

Comment: If you are the member of the union elected by your co-workers who are members of the same union to represent them in your workplace you are the _union representative_ at your workplace, not the other way around.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  我可以说中文吗？我只是想知道，这三个句子是否可以成立？

Comment: @jinglingmen This is an English-only site.

Comment: @Andrew Leach   好的